# MaterialPropertyBlock is used to modify these value

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm unable to change my shader and only see a warning "MaterialPropertyBlock is used to modify these value"

This is across all my spritesheets and sprites. I DON'T have any animations modifying the color values and I'm out of ideas.

It just happened out of the blue and I have tried restarting, re-importing all assets aswell.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MaterialPropertyBlock is used to modify these value

Ignore this warning. It's a know warning that happens to be a [bug](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/why-do-i-have-materialpropertyblock-is-used-to-modify-these-values-on-all-materials.459282/). It should be gone in the next few releases.

> I'm unable to change my shader.

You **can't** change a shader on a default material. You have to create new material, and plug that material to the `SpriteRenderer`'s material slot. You can learn more about this particular issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38592144/3785314).

Comment: Question removed...RIP